# Remove main menu and header from a page in Joomla

Tags: joomla, menu

I want to create one or two pages on my website with no header or main menu or anything - i.e. just the main content.

I am using the Acacia template from Rockettheme. The main menu and the logo are not published as modules, so I do not know how to remove them from specific pages.

Is it possible to create a separate layout or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the template settings if there is any alternative layout. If not, you have to duplicate the template and then tweak the copy to fit your taste.

To duplicate the template depending on your joomla version see [this for J1.5](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=265256) , [this for J2.5](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-how-to-duplicate-and-assign-template-to-some-page.html) or [this for J3.2](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aModifying_a_Joomla!_Template).

After you do that, either hide via css the `header` element like so `header{display:none;}` or remove completely the `<header>...</header>` section from the index page of the template or from where this code is being generated.

Then assign this copy of the template to the pages you want.